# Python & Selenium: How can I obtain a href element from a specific div? My element is stale

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to using selenium with python for web scraping. The webpage I am trying to scrape data from has href elements within a specific div that I am trying to access. I have tried using find_element_by_xpath() to obtain this, however it is stating it cannot find the element. I then tried to find the div using the class and from this find the href, but it states my element is stale. I am struggling to understand why is it stale as I have found this second method seems to work for people on tutorials/stackoverflow.

The basic HTML is like:

```
    <div class=div1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href='path/to/div1stuff/1'>Generic string 1</a>
                <a href='path/to/div1stuff/2'>Generic string 2</a>
                <a href='path/to/div1stuff/3'>Generic string 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>            
    </div>

    <div class=div2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href='path/to/div2stuff/1'>Generic string 1</a>
                <a href='path/to/div2stuff/2'>Generic string 2</a>
                <a href='path/to/div2stuff/3'>Generic string 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>            
    </div>
```

And my python code:

```
class Scraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def execute(self):
        """ Run class methods """

        self.home = "https://www.website2scrape.com/"

        self.get_stuff()


    def get_stuff(self):
        """ Get stuff """

        driver = webdriver.Firefox("/usr/local/bin/")
        driver.get(self.home)

        # Example 1 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='div2']//a[contains(@href,'Generic string 2')]").click()

        # Example 2
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.div2")
        for element in elements:
            print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

Example 1 gives the error element cant be found.

Example 2 gives the error the element is stale

I am trying to click on the generic string 2 href from div2, however if I just get href by using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "Generic string 2")]')
```

it clicks on the href from div1. How can I get the href from a specific div class?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: is second example you search `href` in `div`, not in `a` - you should try `"div.div2 a"`

Comment: in first example you have to use `text()`, not `@href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first example you have to use `text()` instead of `@href`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='div2']//a[contains(text(),'Generic string 2')]").click()
```

In second example you search `href` in `div` but it is in `a` so you have to add `a` to selector

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.div2 a")
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()

html_content = """
    <div class=div1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href='path/to/div1stuff/1'>Generic string 1</a>
                <a href='path/to/div1stuff/2'>Generic string 2</a>
                <a href='path/to/div1stuff/3'>Generic string 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>            
    </div>

    <div class=div2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href='path/to/div2stuff/1'>Generic string 1</a>
                <a href='path/to/div2stuff/2'>Generic string 2</a>
                <a href='path/to/div2stuff/3'>Generic string 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>            
    </div>
"""

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html_content)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.div2 a")
for x in elements:
    print(x.get_attribute('href'))

item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='div2']//a[contains(text(),'Generic string 2')]")
print(item.get_attribute('href'))
item.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! For the second example I am still getting an error:selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='div2']//a[contains(text(),'Generic string 2')]

Comment: maybe HTML looks little different - always in question you should add url so we could see real HTML.

Comment: and in question you should always put FULL error message (starting at word "Tracerback"). There can be other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below xpath to click on second link under div 2 tag.

**Solution 1:**

```
 element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='div2']//ul//li//a[2]"));
 element.click()
```

and if you want to click based on text you can use below code

**Solution 2:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='div2']//a[contains(text(),'Generic string 2')]").click()
```

click based on href element

**Solution 3:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='div2']//ul/li//a[contains(@href,'path/to/div2stuff/2')]").click()
```